# probability that two i.i.d. continuous-time Markov chains end up in different states

Tags: probability, terminology, markov-chains

Say we have two i.i.d. continuous-time Markov chains $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ whose state space is multidimensional and discrete. Also, $X(0) = Y(0)$. I am trying to understand the following:
$$P(X(t) = Y(t)),\,t> 0$$
Or alternatively, $P(X(t) \neq Y(t))$. Is there are name for that probability? Any terms I should search for?

I thought that maybe I should consider the Markov chain $(X(t),Y(t))$. Then I could write down Kolmogorov's forward/backward equations and see where that takes me. However, this seems like a concept that has likely been well-studied.

Thanks.

Comment: Given $X(0)=i$ and $Y(0)=i'$, would this not just be
$$
\sum_{j\in S} P_{ij}(t) P_{i'j}(t),
$$
with $P(t)$ the transition probability matrix of the Markov chains?